# Angularjs: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0

Tags: angularjs, json

When I execute the method saveUser(),it shows the error, but the user can be saved into database. What's wrong?

error info:

> angular1.5.3.min.js:116 SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position 0
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at uc (localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:17:6)
>       at ac (//localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:90:253)
>       at //localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:91:164
>       at q (//localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:7:355)
>       at ed (localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:91:146)
>       at c (/localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:92:403)
>       at localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:128:305
>       at m.$eval (//localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:142:467)
>       at m.$digest (//localhost:8080/js/angular1.5.3.min.js:140:47)(anonymous function) @ angular1.5.3.min.js:116(anonymous function) @ angular1.5.3.min.js:89(anonymous function) @ angular1.5.3.min.js:128$eval @ angular1.5.3.min.js:142$digest @ angular1.5.3.min.js:140$apply @ angular1.5.3.min.js:143g @ angular1.5.3.min.js:95x @

angular1.5.3.min.js:100v.onload @ angular1.5.3.min.js:101

js file:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngResource']);


    app.factory('baseRequest', ["$resource", function ($resource) {

        return $resource("/apis/:id/users.req", {id: '@id'}, {

            query: {method: 'get', isArray: false}
        });

    }]);


    app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "baseRequest", function ($scope, baseRequest) {


        /**
         *   all
         *
         **/

        $scope.fetchAllUsers = function () {

            $scope.users = baseRequest.query();
        };


        /**
         *   first show
         *
         **/

        $scope.fetchAllUsers();

        /**
         *   delete
         *
         **/

        $scope.deleteUser = function (id, name) {

            if (confirm("delete[" + name + "]?")) {

                baseRequest.delete({id: id});
                $scope.fetchAllUsers();

            }
        };

        /**
         *   save
         *
         **/
        $scope.saveUser = function (u) {

            baseRequest.save(u);
            $scope.fetchAllUsers();

        };

    }]);
```

here is the jsp file:

```
<div style="float: left;margin-left: 20px;width: 350px;">

    <span>UserName:</span><input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required><br>
    <span>Password:</span><input type="password" ng-model="user.password" required><br>
    <span>Email:</span><input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required><br>
    <input type="button" ng-click="saveUser(user)" value="save_data"><br>
    <span>user'content：{{user}}</span>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the json you are getting? Where is the addUser function? And baseRequest doesnt have a save function.

Comment: Oh,I am sorry,I just make a mistake. Not addUser function, it should be the saveUser function. I am using the Angularjs $resource methods, so I don't what json it is. Maybe I should try add a save function in baseRequest.

Comment: then same!                                                                                            query: {method: 'get', isArray: false},
save: {method: "POST"}

Comment: And what is the JSON you get?

Comment: I got this json data:

Comment: `{name: "dfgfgf", password: "dfdsfsdf", email: "dfdf@45.com"}
email
:
"dfdf@45.com"
name
:
"dfgfgf"
password
:
"dfdsfsdf"`

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
 this error occurs due to when we define only $state,$localStorage,$routeProvider but we did not use these things in below program so these are the reason to throw an error message